# firebase Query.orderBy* returns unordered list

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm running tests to understands the behavior of of firebase Queries.

this is general function to return the query passed to it:

```
function logVal( query , tag ){
    return query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
         console.log( tag , snapshot.val());
    });
}
```

in this test examples , the returned list is the same as my original data with no ordering!.

```
sRef = firebase.database().ref("students");
logVal ( "orderByChild" , sRef.orderByChild("bio") ) ;
logVal ( "orderByChild" , sRef.orderByChild("chem") ) ;
logVal ( "orderByChild" , sRef.orderByChild("physics") ) ;
logVal ( "orderByKey",  sRef.orderByKey());
logVal ( "orderByValue" , sRef.orderByValue() );
```

this is my model data

```
{
   students: {


  "fahd": {
      "physics": 9,
      "chem"   : 2,
      "bio"    : 0
  }
     ,
     "nasser": {
         "physics": 8,
         "chem"   : 7,
         "bio"    : 6
     }

     ,

     "ahmad": {
      "physics": 7,
      "chem"   : 5,
      "bio"    : 9
    },
    "ali": {
        "physics": 9,
        "chem"   : 9,
        "bio"    : 9
    }
    ,
     "hus": {
         "physics": 10,
         "chem"   : 5,
         "bio"    : 6
     }

   }
}
;
```

Comment: Can you show the actual output so we can see for ourselves exactly what's happening?  And can we see what `sRef` is?

Comment: sRef = firebase.database().ref("students"); & the output is the same as data models

Answer (score 2):

When you call `snapshot.val()` the results are converted into a JSON object. And the order of properties in a JSON objected is by definition undefined.

So if you want to show the results in order, you need to process them using `snapshot.forEach`:

```
return query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
     console.log( tag , child.val());
  });
})
```

---

The second problem is that `orderByValue` will only work if the child nodes have a primitive value. Since your nodes under `users` are JSON objects themselves, they don't have a value that can be sorted on, and thus the nodes are returned in an unspecified order.

Comment: thanks Frank; that is exactly my answer . Please take a look to the suggested edit in it.

Answer (score 0):

I find partial Solution :

when chnging the logVal function to :

```
function logVal( tag, query ){
   return query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      console.log(tag)
      snapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
      var val = snapshot.val();
      console.log("student: " + snapshot.key +
                   "bio: " + val.bio +  
                   "physics: " + val.physics + 
                   " chem: " + val.chem )
 });
 });
 }
```

the output is differ in orderByChild methods. it success in arranging student according to the value of the passed key : ex `chem`

it still return the same data model in `orderByKey` & `orderByValue`.

the error in the original logVal function, may be becouse that dictionary object is non sorted object. so when we call `console.log()` the whole object is converted to array which loss the order.